# how to preg_match number of symbols except newlines?

Tags: php, regex

I want to use PCRE expression make sure the length of all symbols except newlines, matches some range:

`preg_match('/^.{1,7}$/', "some\n\ntxt")`

how can I achieve this ? attempted to use `[^\n]` but without luck

Comment: The simple way is to make a temporary, remove all newlines, then do a bool on the length:  0 < temporary < 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

`^(?:(?:\r?\n)*[^\r\n]){1,7}(?:\r?\n)*$`

https://regex101.com/r/D8lJmv/3

Explained

```
 ^                     # BOS
 (?:                   # Cluster begin
      (?: \r? \n )*         # optional many newlines
      [^\r\n]               # single non-newline
 ){1,7}                # Cluster end, 1 - 7 non-newline chars 
 (?: \r? \n )*         # optional many newlines
 $                     # EOS
```

---

You could also generalize it to whitespaces

`^(?:\s*\S){1,7}\s*$`

Explained

```
 ^                     # BOS
 (?:                   # Cluster begin
      \s*                   # optional many whitespaces
      \S                    # single non-whitspace
 ){1,7}                # Cluster end, 1 - 7 non-whitespace chars 
 \s*                   # optional many whitespaces
 $                     # EOS
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also invert the condition and test if the pattern doesn't matches:

```
if ( !preg_match('/^.{8}/m', "some\n\ntxt") )
```

The m modifier changes the meaning of anchors `^` and `$` that match the start and the end of the line *(instead of the string by default)*.

Comment: Very simple fix to the problem in my answer.

Comment: @Barmar: perhaps: `/^.{0,7}(?:\n.{0,7})*$/` for a "positive" pattern.

Comment: That doesn't allow newlines after the last word.

Comment: Oh, I see it does, because you made the word optional with `{0,7}`

Comment: I only consider myself a demigod with regexp. You're the master. :)

Comment: @Barmar: but there are only masters in SO